# More consistent "Flagged Posts" page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, flag-history

Each user has a "flagged posts" page, at `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/{user-id}`. The display of flags and their outcomes is inconsistent, however.  On mine, I can see the following:

```
XXX moderator attention flags
X   waiting for review
XXX deemed helpful
X   declined
XX  disputed

X   posts marked spam
X   deemed helpful

X   post marked offensive
X   deemed helpful

XX  comments flagged
XX  deemed helpful
X   declined
```

We should see the same results for each type of flag. In other words, "waiting for review," "declined," and "disputed" counts should appear for each of the four groups above.

Note: I'm okay with it not showing a category if there is nothing in it, like declined spam flags (of which I have zero). The problem is that it doesn't always show even if there are flags in that category, like "comments flagged" "waiting for review," of which I currently have 1.

**Edit:** This is still an issue as of July 9, 2014. The key point is that there is no "waiting for review" entry for flags for spam, offensive posts, or comments, even if there are flags waiting for review in those categories. For example, I currently have 2 comment flags pending, but see only the "comments flagged," "deemed helpful," and "declined" counts.

Comment: They are only displayed if you have any items in those categories. If you have spam/offensive declined or even waiting then it will appear.  Are you asking for them to show **0** if you have none?

Comment: Please see my edit. The "waiting for review" category only appears for "moderator attention flags," even when I have flags waiting in the other categories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was implemented in the latest build. The stats presented should now be consistent across all flag types, including waiting for review, disputed, declined, aged away, etc.

It will now look like:

> [image]